# Create a SQL Server trigger that would prevent some users from dropping objects

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2019

I am currently in the process of creating roles in the database and providing permissions (SQL Server).

As part of that I would  like some "roles" to not be able to drop objects in the databases they are part of.

Searching around it looks like the only way would be to use "DDL triggers" and therefore I created a trigger with a condition that would look for the "session role" of the person executing the command and decide whether or not they should be allowed to execute drop.

However the code is not working as expected and I can't find out what the reason is.

Currently it allows people who are part of Role1/Role2 to execute the drop successfully.

I tried the same code without the condition I have created for the role so it applies to everyone and it does work as expected. So it is just the additional "IF" condition that I have which is not working as expected

Does anyone know how I can make a tweak in the code to only restrict users who are part of role1 and role 2 to not be able to drop?

```
CREATE TRIGGER Deny_Drop_Permissions
ON ALL SERVER
FOR DROP_Table, DROP_INDEX, DROP_VIEW, DROP_PROCEDURE
AS
BEGIN 
    IF (SELECT TOP 1 LOWER(r.name) AS role_name
        FROM sys.database_role_members m
        INNER JOIN sys.database_principals r ON m.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals r2 ON m.member_principal_id = r2.principal_id
        INNER JOIN sys.server_principals l ON m.member_principal_id = l.principal_id
        WHERE r2.name = (select session_user)) IN ('Role1', 'Role2')
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('You don''t have the privileges fo drop a table. Please contact your DBA.',16,1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END
END;
```

I asked the user who was part of role1 to execute this code on their end and tell me if they see "Role1" and they do. so the condition is returning the correct value:

```
SELECT TOP 1 LOWER(r.name) AS role_name
FROM sys.database_role_members m
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals r ON m.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals r2 ON m.member_principal_id = r2.principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.server_principals l ON m.member_principal_id = l.principal_id
WHERE r2.name = (SELECT session_user)
```

Comment: Souhds like you're reinventing the wheel. Why don't you just put a `DENY DROP` permission on the tables for those users? https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15848/220697 Alternatively, change their database role so they only have `SELECT` permissions

Comment: it seems like you are only selecting top (1) so lets say for instance your user is in Role1, Role2, Role3 ... Role3 might be that top row selected. Unless you can only have one role, then ignore me ;) I also find this has an icky feeling using triggers to implement permissions - will be difficult to maintain, understand, debug ... lots of cons not much in the way of pros.